# innerHTML inserts only [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

i want to insert a htmlsnippet into another html-element

i tried it this way

the html

```
<div class="box1">
    insert this html element
</div>
<div class="box2">
  into this
</div>
```

the js

```
var box1 = document.querySelectorAll(".box1")[0]; 
var box2 = document.querySelectorAll(".box2")[0];
console.log(box1);
box2.innerHTML = box1;
```

but it doesnt work it only insert [object HTMLDivElement], if i look at the console it puts out the correct html, what im doing it wrong?

and yeah i dont want to use the $ libary ;)

http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/MKQOwy

thanks ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`innerHTML` doesn't insert DOM nodes, just strings.
Use `appendChild` instead

```
var box1 = document.querySelector(".box1"); 
var box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");

box2.appendChild( box1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method.

```
box2.appendChild(box1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
box2.appendChild(box1);
```